# Mod_Rewrite Error code: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2

As stated in the title, I encounter a redirect loop when accessing my pages in the website.

Here is my rewrite config.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://example\.com/test/store\.do [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)$ /test/$1 [R]
```

So, how do I solve this redirect error?

Here is the log file

```
[Fri May 16 12:18:20.345204 2014] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 29462:tid 1193511232] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 172.16.28.96:60187] 172.16.28.96 - - [example.com/sid#1e84d1c0][rid#1e954910/initial] applying pattern '(.*)$' to uri '/test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test/ /store.do', referer: http://example.com/test/store.do
[Fri May 16 12:18:20.345213 2014] [rewrite:trace4] [pid 29462:tid 1193511232] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 172.16.28.96:60187] 172.16.28.96 - - [example.com/sid#1e84d1c0][rid#1e954910/initial] RewriteCond: input='http://example.com/test/store.do' pattern='^http://example\\.com/test/store\\.do' [NC] => matched, referer: http://example.com/test/store.do
[Fri May 16 12:18:20.345218 2014] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 29462:tid 1193511232] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 172.16.28.96:60187] 172.16.28.96 - - [example.com/sid#1e84d1c0][rid#1e954910/initial] rewrite '/test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//whatshot_v3/hahah/store.do' -> '/test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//store.do', referer: http://example.com/test/store.do
[Fri May 16 12:18:20.345233 2014] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 29462:tid 1193511232] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 172.16.28.96:60187] 172.16.28.96 - - [example.com/sid#1e84d1c0][rid#1e954910/initial] explicitly forcing redirect with http://example.com/test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test/ /store.do, referer: http://example.com/test/store.do
[Fri May 16 12:18:20.345239 2014] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 29462:tid 1193511232] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 172.16.28.96:60187] 172.16.28.96 - - [example.com/sid#1e84d1c0][rid#1e954910/initial] escaping http://example.com/test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//store.do for redirect, referer: http://example.com/test/store.do
[Fri May 16 12:18:20.345245 2014] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 29462:tid 1193511232] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 172.16.28.96:60187] 172.16.28.96 - - [example.com/sid#1e84d1c0][rid#1e954910/initial] redirect to http://example.com/test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//store/store.do [REDIRECT/302], referer: http://example.com/test/store.do
```

---

**UPDATE:**

I have found the solution for my problem.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://example\.com/test/store\.do [NC]
RewriteRule ^/test - [R,L] #prevent for any URL to be place under /test.Thus , prevent looping.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://example\.com/test/store\.do [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /test/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: Why are you using {HTTP_REFERER}? This is not the variable for the request.

Comment: because i need to specify only from this url condition , only can met the rule. Because i doing reverse proxy , so if i use the hostname , it will affect all.

Comment: I am not sure I understood what you said (I may be too tired), but I think I would be using {REQUEST_URI} or {REQUEST_FILENAME}.

Comment: for rewriteCond? how can i modify it?

Comment: In your example, is example.com your site?

Comment: ya....it just a test server. But i doing reverse proxy , so it will be like example.com/test. Then it will jump to example.com/test/store.do.

Comment: What are the URLs for the backend server?   Are you putting these rewrite rules on the front end (where the reverse proxy is), or on the backend (the machine hosting the store)?

Answer (score 2):

It has been nearly 12 years since I have done any proxy work so I am at a disadvantage. At one point proxies were something I knew cold and configured daily, but tonight, I am just not getting my head around this. As well, I am very adept at doing extremely weird things using .htaccess but not so much for the normal stuff that people do. However, I do see some errors that I will address and throw in some other thoughts that might help.

I invite people to jump in and correct anything I may have made a mistake on. Please.

Your rule creates a loop. Your RewriteRule created the exact condition that the RewriteCond is designed to trap. Each time a rewrite is made, in effect, the entire validation process is started over only to be trapped again and so on. You need an out.

As well, you are using the $1 variable without filling the variable using () in the RewriteCond. If you were trying to fill this in the RewriteRule, then you are appending the original request to /test/ which I do not think you want.

Just addressing these few things...

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://example\.com/test/$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://example\.com/test/store\.do$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* /test/ [R,L]
```

The first line is your out. It basically says, *if I see the condition I just created, then forget it*- all is okay.

I treated this as a standard rewrite, however, while I use HTTP_REFERER for about 60% of my work, I am not sure it applies here. You may be the best judge. Referrer is not the request. It is the *from* location and not the *to* location. In other words, it is the page the person has left and not the page the person is going to. Here is another option to try.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/test/$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/test/store\.do$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* /test/ [R,L]
```

I mentioned {REQUEST_FILENAME} in my comments, but I am not sure this is what you want, but on the off chance you want to experiment, it refers to the store.do. You may also noticed that I book-ended the regular expressions with both ^ and $. While this is not always necessary, it is generally safer to do.

Let me know if I was able to help. I can always take another SWAG at it.

Comment: still getting same error.you can see my log file i updated.

Comment: I am seeing some things that confuse me. You still have *applying pattern '(.*)$'* and *whatshot_v3/hahah/store.do*. As well, this well into the loop so it is a bit hard to tell what's going on. I also see that you are using %{HTTP_REFERER} which confuses me. I will have to think on this for a bit.

Comment: @w3d I am not sure if you will see this... but if you can understand this question, I differ to your expertise. Can you make sense of this? Please let me know.

Comment: 19 months later... @closetnoc I've just stumbled across your comment! But no, I can't say I understand it either! The question seems to be lacking a clear purpose, which kinda makes it a bit difficult to answer. But certainly, using the HTTP Referer in this way does seem to be the wrong thing to do. (?)

Comment: @w3d I think back when I wrote this I did not realize you would not see it unless you had written the answer or a comment. Ooopppsss!! Sometimes you learn things a little too late.

Answer (score 1):

> I am doing reverse proxy, so when a user enters `example.com/test`. I want it to jump to `example.com/test/store.do`.

If this is your problem, then your rewrite rule should be very simple:

```
RewriteRule /test/?$ /test/store.do [R]
```

You really shouldn't be using the referrer in you rewrite rule unless you want to block change what people see based on where they came from.   For example, show an error message when people come from some a specific other website.

Here are the reasons that your rewrite rule was failing:

- You were saying: "If somebody come from `/test/store.do`, add an extra `/test` to the beginning of their current page and redirect.
- The browser would add the extra test and redirect, but redirects don't change the referrer.  It would send the same referrer again, which would trigger the same rule.
- You would keep adding `/test` and redirecting until you get too many redirects.

I'm not sure exactly how being behind a reverse proxy is figuring in to your problem.   You should have two sets of URLs.   One that is user visible, and one that is backend only.   Something like:

- Front end: `http://example.com/test/store.do`
- Back end: `http://127.0.0.1:8080/commercepackage/2012/store.do`

You don't say which of these hosts is having the rewrite rule on it. If it is on the back end, your rewrite rules should use the path on the backend (`/commercepackage/2012`), not the path the users see (`/test`).